# In QT, how do I obtain the line ending in a platform independent way?

Tags: c++, qt

Using the QT library, is there a simple way to obtain the line ending characters particular to the platform where the program is being executed?

How can I obtain the line ending characters as a QString?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with text files, open files in text mode and use `\n`. Please note that using `endl` is [no more portable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8689547/2316442) than `\n`.

Comment: In addition, you need to set `QIODevice::Text` as an additional flag when opening the file, so that `\n` is properly translated to the platform-specific line ending.

Comment: When working with text files QT takes care of the end line characters for you. But what about getting the end line characters in a QString to further do something with these?

Comment: @UndeadKernel It becomes important when you're reading or writing the string into files. If you use `\n` and text mode for your file operations, that would be fine.