# std::endl in a string variable?

Tags: c++, string, std, endl

Hi i want to save multiply lines in a string. I got a string logstring and i want to save multiplay error logs which i later can print in a txt file or as a console output. Is there a possibility to use endl to format a string variable? I searched the internet but i only find

```
cout << "" << endl;
```

Now my idea was:

```
std::string logstring;
logstring = logstring + "Error Message" + "Number" + "Time + Date";
logstring += endl;
```

Is something like this possible or is there no way to format string variables? Later i want to print them to a log.txt file? Is it possible to use a string like this?

```
std::ofstream logfile;
logfile.open(log.txt);
logfile << logstring;
```

The text file should look like this

```
Error Message 1 Date
Error Message 2 Date
Error Message 3 Date
...
```

Is it possibly to get it like this or do i have to print all lines seperatly?

Comment: `logstring = logstring + "\n" + "Error Message" + "\n" + "Number" ...;

Comment: or `stringstream`?

Comment: ty all for your answers, "\n" fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget `std::endl` adds a new line *and* flushes the buffer.

If you simply want new lines, `\n`, add them to your string, using `+` or stream them to a stream, using `<< '\n'`.

For example,

```
std::string logstring;
logstring = logstring + "Error Message" + "Number" + "Time + Date";
logstring += '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Use `logstring += "\n";` instead

Answer (score 0):

[`std::endl`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/endl/) isn't only a `\n` (newline) character, but it also flushes the stream.

If you have a file open in 'text-mode', your operating system should replace `\n` with the correct platform specific end of line character(sequence). So simply appending a `\n` should be fine. [Portable end of line (newline)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689344/portable-end-of-line-newline)

Also note that by default, standard input and output are opened in textmode with msvc.

Answer (score 0):

To separate lines in a string you should use the new line escape character `'\n'`.

For example

```
std::string logstring;

//...

logstring += "Error Message 1 Date";
logstring += '\n';

logstring += "Error Message 2 Date";
logstring += '\n';

logstring += "Error Message 3 Date";
logstring += '\n';
```

As for `std::endl` then it is a function declared like

```
template <class charT, class traits>
basic_ostream<charT, traits>& endl(basic_ostream<charT, traits>& os);
```

It is a so-called stream manipulator. Fo example in this statement

```
std::cout << std::endl;
```

there is used `operator <<` that accepts pointer to the function as an argument.

You can not concatenate a string with the function pointer `std::endl` and if you did this somehow it did not make sense.